# Can't Star a repo or a file in Github

Tags: github

I'm on an Enterprise License and for some unknown reason, I can't star any repo or file. When I click on `Star`, the following message appears: `You can't perform that action at this time.`

I haven't been able to find resource online to solve this issue. Has anyone ran into this scenario before?

Comment: Last time I saw this, it was due to my SSO timed out. I refreshed the page and logged back in via SSO, and it worked.

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming questions. This looks like it would be better directed at GitHub support (I imagine that, with an Enterprise license, you're entitled to some level of support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found a way to make it work. I created a list and then stared the repo that I wanted to that list. It is a strange case because I didn't have to do it this way before on other accounts. However, this solves it for me. Just wanted to post the answer in case someone else runs into similar scenario.